# Scale SVG image with maximum saving of quality

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an image of a window part in SVG format, When I try to set it up in HTML block as a background image, or with an absolute position, the quality of the image is getting worse. For example, I can not see a window opening trigger. How can I fix it, and what properties do I need to change in SVG to see borders of the window and trigger of the door without losing any quality?
I uploaded HTML Code to show example:

```css
.box-item{
  position:relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 290px;
}
.box-item svg{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-item">
<svg id="üheosaline_aken" preserveAspectRatio="none" data-name="üheosaline aken" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="465" height="675">
  <metadata><?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c138 79.159824, 2016/09/14-01:09:01        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""/>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>            
<?xpacket end="w"?></metadata>
<defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #f2f2f2;
        stroke: #f2f2f2;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #939393;
        stroke-width: 1px;
      }

      .cls-2, .cls-3 {
        stroke: #939393;
      }

      .cls-3 {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke-width: 0.5px;
      }

      .cls-4 {
        fill: #d8a50e;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect class="cls-1" x="-14" y="-11" width="493" height="697"/>
  <rect id="Rectangle_594_copy_4" data-name="Rectangle 594 copy 4" class="cls-2" x="6" y="7" width="455" height="657"/>
  <g id="parem">
    <rect id="Rectangle_594_copy_6" data-name="Rectangle 594 copy 6" class="cls-2" x="170.906" y="24.969" width="265.938" height="625"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_594_copy_7" data-name="Rectangle 594 copy 7" class="cls-3" width="465" height="675"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_594_copy_7-2" data-name="Rectangle 594 copy 7" class="cls-2" x="39" y="41" width="386" height="594"/>
    <path class="cls-4" d="M420.03,40.994l3.988,1.925L43.009,338l-3.987-1.924Z"/>
    <path class="cls-4" d="M424.018,632.06l-3.988,1.925L39.022,338.938l3.987-1.925Z"/>
    <rect id="rosett" class="cls-3" x="8.375" y="299.969" width="25.031" height="49.969" rx="3" ry="3"/>
    <path id="käepide" class="cls-3" d="M14,312H27a0,0,0,0,1,0,0v74a2,2,0,0,1-2,2H16a2,2,0,0,1-2-2V312A0,0,0,0,1,14,312Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Updated my answer, by adding existing situation and what do Im looking for:

This is what I have now:[image]

This is what I want to achieve:[image]

The place of the trigger and yellow lines does not matter here, only thing that is important is the quality of the trigger and borders of the window.

Comment: your svg is wrong : there is no unit for size, as the viewbox

Comment: even if I remove it, nothing changes

Comment: @MisterJojo can you put the correct code please?

Comment: @MisterJojo updated my question, look at screenshots, please.

Answer (score 0):

see by yourself :

```css
svg { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.r-1 {  fill: #f2f2f2; stroke: #939393; stroke-width: 100;  }
.r-2 {  fill: #939393;   }
.l-n {  stroke: #d8a50e; stroke-width: 100; stroke-linecap: round }
div {  
  width: 240px; 
  height: 580px;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4800 11600">
    <rect class="r-1" x="50" y="50" width="4700" height="11500" />
    <rect class="r-2" x="400" y="400" width="4000" height="10800" />
    <line class="l-n" x1="450" y1="450"  x2="4350" y2="5750" />
    <line class="l-n" x1="4350" y1="5750"  x2="450" y2="11150" />
    <line class="l-n" x1="450" y1="11150"  x2="2350" y2="450" />
    <line class="l-n" x1="2350" y1="450" x2="4350" y2="11150"   />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Still the same result. If I put it into a <div> and give it position absolute, trigger are not seen properly.

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov you do not need a div. svg element accept position everything

Comment: Unfortunately for this task, I need a div, and SVG inside of it.

Comment: Yes, but window trigger is not visible on your version.

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov  wiitch  window trigger ??  none of your SVG element have this name

Comment: Look to my svg example please, there is window trigger in the right middle corner.

Answer (score 0):

You're sizing your SVG in multiple places. I think you really want to do a viewBox rather than a width/height in your SVG element aka:

```
    <svg id="üheosaline_aken" preserveAspectRatio="none" data-name="üheosaline aken" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-30 -30 520 800">
```

Comment: Not working unfortunately, in this case, height of SVG is 162px, while height of DIV is 190px.

Comment: Look to the image I uploaded, and upload full code please.

Comment: Ah - if you tweak your viewBox and remove the sizing from the SVG element - you should get what you're looking for - just updated the viewBox dimensions in the answer. You just need to replace the opening SVG tag with what I have up there.

Comment: If I remove sizing from the svg it will not take full div and height of parent div. By the way, if you are an expert in SVG, maybe we can chat, so I can explain issue better?